# laravel enum validation rule

Tags: laravel, api

I want to validate an enum in laravel, but it's not clear to me how to do this.

In my database I have an enum attribute and the migration converts the enum to an array type (e.g. `enum('Delta','Statisch')` -> `array('Delta','Statisch')`). But how do I validate the enum/ the data which I receive (how do I know which value of the enum has been selected and how can I ensure that the received value is part of the enum)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is easy:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class DummyController extends Controller 
{

    public function store(Request $request) 
    {
    
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'filed_name' => ['required', Rule::in(['Delta','Statisch'])
        ]);
    }
}
```

Checkout [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-in) for more info.

Comment: you forgot to close a bracket it needs to be `])]
]);`. I can not edit your answer, because it would be less than 5 changes.

Comment: can I incorporate your answer into a model, more specific into the `$rules` variable? When I try following: `public static $rules = [
'op' => [Rule::in('a', 'b')]
];` i get an `expression is not allowed as field default value` error.

Comment: Yes you can do it any way you choose...the takeaway is the `Rule::in()`.

Comment: Wait, where is my error? I thought I can use Rule::in(['a', 'b'])

Comment: you cant use a dynamic value on a class property, what you can do is something like this: `public function rules(): array { return [ 'op' => [Rule::in('a', 'b')] ];}`

Comment: So I have to remove my `public static $rules = [ /* ... */ ];` variable and replace it with `function rules(): array { return [ /* ... */ ] };`? Sorry for the overwhealming amount of questions.

Comment: No amount of questions is overwhelming, we are all learning. And yes replace it like so.

Answer (score 1):

*Try This*

```
use Validator;

$validator = Validator::make([
    'type' => 'in:Delta,Statisch', // DEFAULT or SOCIAL values
]);
```

Comment: Is it possible to also check for an option containing spaces (e.g. `make it so`)

Comment: And to check for commas